# Understanding the error when installing npm install node-bluetooth

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm

I have a script that is not in a webpage, it is there by itself. I am compiling and running it using Node 16. I am trying to install `node-bluetooth` by using `npm install node-bluetooth`, but I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/BluetoothSerialPort/src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.19.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/bill/.cache/node-gyp/16.19.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/bill/.cache/node-gyp/16.19.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/bill/.cache/node-gyp/16.19.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:18:6: error: variable or field ‘InitAll’ declared void
npm ERR!    18 | void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |      ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:18:14: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!    18 | void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |              ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:18:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!    18 | void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:18:29: error: ‘exports’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!    18 | void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
npm ERR!       |                             ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:12:
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:23:34: error: ‘InitAll’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!    23 | NODE_MODULE(BluetoothSerialPort, InitAll)
npm ERR!       |                                  ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/bill/.cache/node-gyp/16.19.0/include/node/node.h:887:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!   887 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                    ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:23:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!    23 | NODE_MODULE(BluetoothSerialPort, InitAll)
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [BluetoothSerialPort.target.mk:119: Release/obj.target/BluetoothSerialPort/src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-32-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/bill/Documents/WaterCoaster/node_modules/node-bluetooth
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.19.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bill/.npm/_logs/2023-03-12T14_24_59_199Z-debug-0.log
```

I have 2 questions:

1. what should I look for when debugging this error? What are the most crucial parts of the log?
2. What could cause such an error?

Comment: From the docs: 

```
Requirements
This package require node-gyp installed .

Linux
You'll need libbluetooth-dev. On Ubuntu/Debian : $ sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

Comment: @Pandelis I have tried that, but the error message did not change.

Comment: i see.

Okay well what normally happens with NPM libraries is sometimes they need to compile C libraries under the hood. thats what is happening here.

The C code it is trying to compile behind the scenes is failing to build.

the important parts are everything after:

./src/linux/BluetoothSerialPort.cc:18:6: error: variable or field ‘InitAll’ declared void
npm ERR!    18 | void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {.

Comment: @Pandelis I have gcc installed. I don't know what else to do. But thank you for mentioning the important information of the message.

Comment: sometimes trying an older version of node might work, i see the bluetooth lib is 4 years, old the LTS version of node at that time would of been node 8